# Use $Concat with UpdateOne to update the subobject string field Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using mongo-java-driver for mongodb connection and wanted to update one field in subobject of the record.

Record:

```
{
    "_id": "61866c32d11c9aefb01125f7",
    "number": 1900,
    "oms": "ters",
    "data": [
        {
            "empCode": "EMP2",
            "firstname": "vivek",
            "lastname": "bdh",
            "age": 30
        },
        {
            "empCode": "EMP3",
            "firstname": "ravi",
            "lastname": "sh",
            "age": 30
        }
    ],
    "volgnummer": 1
}
```

I wanted to update lastname where empCode = "EMP2".

Following is my code snippet to perform the operation

```
public class FixDataApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MongoCollection collection = MongoConfig.getCollection(args[0], args[1], "myCollection");
        

        BasicDBObject concat = new BasicDBObject();
        concat.put("$concat",  Arrays.asList(
                new BsonString("data.$.lastname"),
                new BsonString(" TestAppendStr")));

        BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
        updateFields.append( "data.$.lastname", concat);

        BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
        command.put("$set", updateFields);

        UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(
                Filters.and(
                        Filters.eq("_id", "61866c32d11c9aefb01125f7"),
                        Filters.eq("data.empCode", "EMP2")
                ),
                command
        );
        System.out.println("Record updated successfully " + result.getModifiedCount());
    }
}
```

When I'm executing the above application getting following error...

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'data.0.lastname.$concat' is not valid for storage.
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1060)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1037)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:622)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:617)
    at common.FixDataApp.main(FixDataApp.java:30)
```

Can anyone help to update such field with $concat and update method.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit complex MongoDB update query.

As you are updating a document in the array field and at the same time you are using `$concat`, which requires an aggregation pipeline.

Without `$concat` (aggregation pipeline), you can use `arrayFilters` and `$[elem]` which can be straight and easier to update desired document field in the nested array.

---

The main points in the below query:

`$map` - Iterate and update for each document in `data` array field.

`$cond` - When meets requirement, the `lastname` field will be updated with the value from `$concat`. Else it will be updated with the original value.

`$mergeObjects` - Merge the original document `$emp` with new updated field, `lastname`.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "61866c32d11c9aefb01125f7",
  "data.empCode": "EMP2"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "emp",
          "in": {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$emp",
              {
                "lastname": {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$emp.empCode",
                        "EMP2"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: {
                      $concat: [
                        "$$emp.lastname",
                        " TestAppendStr"
                      ]
                    },
                    else: "$$emp.lastname"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9aQY5PMXyh)